# FullCalendar - Event spanning all day are one day too short

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm passing to fullcalendar an event like this one:

```
{
     id: 31,
     title: 'Test',
     start: '2014-12-22',
     end: '2014-12-23',
     allDay: true
}
```

I expected to find in the calendar an event that spans two whole days, but the event is only in the `2014-12-22` slot, not in the `2014-12-23` one. The nextDayThreshold parameter is set to `00:00:00`, but according to the documentation it should be ignored when allDay is set to true. I'm sure that allDay is correctly interpreted because in the agenda view the event appears in the all-day row.

How can I set fullcalendar to display such an event in both days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this a conscious design decision, in that all end dates are to be regarded as exclusive, based on discussions like [this](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=921) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=689), i.e. so despite being an all day event, your end date is not regarded as included (inclusive) of the dates tagged. e.g. If you have a start date of `2015-03-01 00:00:00` and an end date of `2015-03-02 00:00:00` the *span* is only one day.

This seems to coincide with the [version 2 upgrade to using moment.js](http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/). So it would appear you will either need to add '23:59:59' to your end date, or to find a a different way of specifying the end date, e.g. as a duration of two days added to the start date?

Comment: This is a terrible decision if that is the case

Comment: Can you still resize the events in month view if a time is added to the event object? Resize and Drag and Drop also always add another day than what is shown. I've been fiddling, trying to get a solution but to no avail.

Comment: I had/have that issue too. Changing the time didn't help, I actually have to add +1 day to the end date.. That's ridiculous but it seems to work.

Comment: Ridiculous indeed... I am using this date format `start: new Date(2016, 11, 27),`, so adding a 00:00:00 time doesnt fit. I too landed up adding a day for display purposes..

Answer (score 8):

Based on the [eventDataTransform function](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/) you could add 1 day if your event is allDay. Note that this will only affect rendering.

```
eventDataTransform: function(event) {                                                                                                                                
  if(event.allDay) {                                                                                                                                               
    event.end = moment(event.end).add(1, 'days')                                                                                                                 
  }
  return event;  
}
```

Comment: I got this to work, but still doesn't fix resizing or moving events in month view. (i.e. when calender initially loads the events render correctly, but when moving or resizing events the end date is set to one day longer then visually represented).

Answer (score 0):

on ajax GET all events add one day

```js
moment(end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS')
```

on ajax POST (update) subtract(1, 'days')

```js
moment(eventChange_end, 'YYYY-MM-DD').subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS')
```