# Fullcalendar and logic event interval

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I'm thinking about Fullcalendar on my site. When I download and run demo with a JSON file I see:

```
{
"title": "Long Event",
"start": "2015-02-07",
"end": "2015-02-10"
},
```

Then on calendar it shows like 2 days!
On [fullcalendar.io](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) they wrote about `end` param:

> For example, if the last full day of an event is Thursday, the exclusive end of the event will be 00:00:00 on Friday!

Even on [fullcalendar.io](http://fullcalendar.io) website that doesn't work!

Any idea how to solve this?

JS Bin example : [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/wutobikoli/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 1):

You misread, although the description in the fullcalendar docs is confusing.

They state this about the `end` parameter: just before the bit you quoted.

> It is the moment immediately after the event has ended.

This means that if you want an event to end on Thursday, you need to set `end` to Friday, 00:00.

Comment: oh,ok. but still... if my user set date from datepicker from 2015-02-07 to 2015-02-10 and i sent that to my databese ('datetime') then JSON return this data to calendar and show that event like 2015-02-07T00:00:00 to 2015-02-10T00:00:00 - that means till 2015-02-09 midnight, not 2015-02-10 in allDay mode. Something i dont understand here

Comment: Your datepicker apparently uses an *inclusive* end time, while the fullcalendar feed uses an *exclusive* end time.

Comment: datepicker send `datetime` properly: `2015-02-07 00:00:00` and end `2015-02-10 00:00:00` and check that as a `allDay=true`.what i can change? i dont want to add `+1D` to my database

Comment: Both are 'proper', but their definition is different. You will either have to add a day to everything in your database or add the date when you render the feed,  change what fullcalendar is doing, or change your date picker. None of these components is wrong in their interpretation of what 'end' means, the interpretations just differ.

Comment: i found this topic [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604359/fullcalendar-event-spanning-all-day-are-one-day-too-short) its looks that i must change my datepicker or Fullcalendar script :( All end dates are now exclusive using 'MomentJS'