# Fullcalendar: display multi days event in allDay event?

Tags: javascript, events, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar version 3.6.2 with some events.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            navLinks: true,
            nextDayThreshold: '00:00:00', // 9am
            events: [
               {
                    title: 'Tesst tesst',
                    allDay: false,
                    start: '2017-11-12T08:00:00',
        end: '2017-11-13T15:00:00'
                },
                {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2017-11-19T10:00:00',
        end: '2017-11-21T06:00:00'
    },
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    allDay:true,
                    start: TOMORROW,
                    end: TOMORROW
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                        start: '2017-11-07T10:00:00',
        end: '2017-11-10T06:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                        start: '2017-11-26T10:00:00',
        end: '2017-11-28T04:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    allDay: true,
                    start: TODAY + 'T10:30:00',
                    end: TODAY + 'T12:30:00'
                },
            ]
        });
```

My plunk: [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZT2o8IMs33iuB11UZ5aa?p=preview)

I want to make long events display in all-day event in agendaWeek/agendaDay like Allday event.

Any way to do this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: A bit confused by the question, you want events that span multiple days to show in the allday tab? set attribute 'allDay' to true for those events like in the demo.

Comment: @jones, if i set 'allDay': true, Long event display wrong, example: 'Long Event' will display from 2017-11-07 to 2017-11-09 if i set allDay: true, instead from 2017-11-07 to 2017-11-10

Comment: That is not "wrong" as per the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ says for the "end" property: "The **exclusive** date/time an event ends...It is the moment immediately after the event has ended. For example, if the last full day of an event is **Thursday**, the exclusive end of the event will be 00:00:00 on **Friday**!" In other words, the code is behaving exactly as documented in that situation.

Comment: I know that. But in my project, my customer wants the 4-day event to be displayed in 4 days, and in agendaWeek/agendaDay, this event must be displayed on the all-day tab.

Comment: well surely it's obvious: in your data make it end a 24hrs earlier. Then it should show up as you need.

Comment: @ADyson, can you provide a plunk, I try change data but not as expected.

Comment: please show what you changed it to.

Comment: sorry I think maybe I should have said make it 24hrs later. http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/67/

Comment: @ADyson, let see event "Tesst tesst", if you set allDay attribute is true to display it on all-day tab in Week/Day view, this event is only appear in a day

Comment: yes because if you make something allDay, the time component is ignored. An "all day" event with start/end _times_ makes no sense, so fullCalendar ignores the times if you supply them. Therefore it ends at the end of the 12th (because the end date, is exclusive (as per the rule I mentioned above), and the end is now just the 13th at 00:00:00, because the time you gave is ignored). To make it still span the second day you'd have to set the end date to the 14th. But if these events have defined start and end times, I don't understand why you want to make them into "all Day" events - they're not.

Comment: @ADyson, thanks so much, I will reconsider this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem, try this:

The `eventDataTransform` Is key here, this allows you to manipulate the data before it’s rendered on to the calendar.

In my example, because others that create events on our calendar frequently create multi-day events that then take up most of the screen in `agendaDay` view, I opted to reclassify these events as all day events which relocates them to the top of the view.

I’ve chosen to reclassify any event >=5 hours as an all day event.
It’s important to catch `eventData.end == null` as well!

Multi day events will need to be identified further as to those which need the end date redefining to midnight the following morning. This is useful where for example as multi-day event finishes at 1500hrs on the last day this will also be moved to the top as an all day event. Without this amendment the last day will be cut off. There’s some more info on this here: [FullCalendar - Event spanning all day are one day too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604359/fullcalendar-event-spanning-all-day-are-one-day-too-short)

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: '',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
          defaultView: 'month',
          editable: false,
          aspectRatio: 0.77,
        eventDataTransform: function (eventData) {

                var dur = eventData.end - eventData.start; //total event duration

                if(dur >= 18000000 || eventData.end == null){ // 5 hours

                        eventData.allDay = true;


                        //eventData.end needs ammending to 00:00:00 of the next morning
                        if (dur > 86400000) {


                        var m = moment(eventData.end);
                        var roundDown = m.startOf('day');
                        var day2 = moment(roundDown).add(1, 'days')

                        eventData.end = day2.toString();

                        }

                }

            return(eventData);  
        },

    });
```

Comment: Explaining your code, and how it differs from the code posted in the answer would greatly increase the quality of this answer.

Comment: Revised as per your comments. Hope that helps